# maven activate by property value and version

Tags: maven, maven-3

is there a way to activate a profile by property but instead of checking a specific value check for a version range.
here is what i am trying to do

```
<properties>
  <frontend-maven-plugin.version>0.0.16</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>
...
...
<profile>
  <id>new_version_of_frontend</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>maven.version</name>
      <value>3.1.0</value>
    </property>
    <properties>
      <frontend-maven-plugin.version>0.0.23</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>
  </activation>
</profile>
```

so the above works (set the frontend plugin version to 0.0.23 when maven version is 3.1.0

what i would like to do is change the condition to 3.1.0 and above something like

```
<value>[3.1.0,)</value>
```

but property value check does not support version range. is there any other way to do this? or even check if version is 3.1+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no such functionality with out-of-the-box Maven. Maven is usually really simple when looking into its internals. Profile activation based on property is basically about two strings equality, nothing more, no extra logic here.

I can image a solution that introduces own, simple Maven plugin that does the actual range mechanism and set a property like `frontend-maven-plugin.version.within.range` to value of `true` or `false`. Then your profile activation condition is based on `true` value of a given property. It might work if you launch your plugin early enough, probably during `initialize` phase of the lifecycle. I'm not sure however if profiles activation is even earlier or not. You need to verify this.